# Web service method call times out, metadata request works fine

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, timeout

I have a **WCF service** which is not responding to method calls. On the client side, I get timeouts when I call any method.

Interestingly, when I update the reference on Visual Studio it works fine. It responds to metadata requests as expected.

Looking at the Windows **Event Log** (on the server), I see the message `App Pool exceeded time limits during shut down`.

And looking at **IIS log**, I see the message `Connection_Abandoned_By_AppPool FooBar`, where `FooBar` is the name of the application pool.

Can anyone tell me why my WCF service is not responding to client requests?

---

Here is the **web.config** on the server:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FooBarBehaviors">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="FooBarBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1048576" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
      <service name="FooBarSvc.FooBar" behaviorConfiguration="FooBarBehaviors">
        <endpoint contract="FooBarSvc.FooBar" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="FooBarBinding" address="" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Please add your code and config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was a problem with a component I'm using. The web service is fine, but the component hangs, making the method call to take forever to return, therefore, being abandoned and causing timeouts on client side.